# I want to turn the input buttons from grey to black

Tags: css

I'm creating a webpage with no js , and the llok I have is perfect except for one the grey input/submit boxes , I've tried all sorts of options with buttons code  but cant turn them black or blue or even transparent , is it possible ? if yes how ? someone please help

```css
.input { 
  background-color: transparent; 
  background: #7ec2cf; 
  color: #eaed5e; 
  font-size: 15px; 
  line-height: 15px; 
  padding: 3px; 
  border-radius: 2px; 
  font-family: Georgia, serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-style: normal; 
  font-variant: small-caps; 
  text-transform: none; 
  border-color: #7ec2cf; 
  border-style: #7ec2cf 2px; 
  display: inline-block; 
} 

.input:hover { 
  background: #eaed5e; 
  color: #7ec2cf
} 

.input:active { 
  background: #7ec2cf; 
  color: #eaed5e
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input value="Logout" type="submit">
</div>

<input name="a" value="lo" type="hidden">
<input name="s" value="0oiRYW3Nvf0YC1Fk" type="hidden">
```

Comment: @gavcollins please add the relevant CSS in the code snippet not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<form method="post">
<div>
<input value="Logout" type="button" class="press">
</div>
<input name="a" value="lo" type="hidden">
<input name="s" value="0oiRYW3Nvf0YC1Fk" type="hidden">
</form>
```

css:

```
.press {
   background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.input:hover { background: #eaed5e; color: #7ec2cf} .input:active { background: #7ec2cf; color: #eaed5e }
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your css is the selector you're using - .input which represents class names input, for the selecting the button either use -

```
.input input{
//your code here for the button
}
```

or

```
.input>input{
//your code here for the button
}
```

or just

```
input {
//your code here for the button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example. Just remove the div and apply the `.input` class to the `input` element. Also note that `background-color` redundant in this case.

```css
.input { 
  background: #7ec2cf; 
  color: #eaed5e; 
  font-size: 15px; 
  line-height: 15px; 
  padding: 3px; 
  border-radius: 2px; 
  font-family: Georgia, serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-style: normal; 
  font-variant: small-caps; 
  text-transform: none; 
  border-color: #7ec2cf; 
  border-style: #7ec2cf 2px; 
  display: inline-block; 
} 

.input:hover { 
  background: #eaed5e; 
  color: #7ec2cf
} 

.input:active { 
  background: #7ec2cf; 
  color: #eaed5e
}
```

```html
<input value="Logout" type="submit" class="input">

<input name="a" value="lo" type="hidden">
<input name="s" value="0oiRYW3Nvf0YC1Fk" type="hidden">
```